# Error al crear tabla utilizando Spring Boot y postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring, spring-boot

¡Un saludo a todos!

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación utilizando Spring y Postgres. Actualmente tengo 3 entidades las cuales son: `User`, `Role` y `UserRole`

**User**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
    private char gender;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true)
    private String email;


    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, char gender, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**Role**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    public Role () {}

    public Role (String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

**UserRole**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    public UserRole () {}

    public UserRole (User user, Role role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

A la hora de correr el proyecto, tanto las tablas `Role` como `UserRole` se crean de manera correcta en la base de datos. Sin embargo, la tabla `User` no logra crearse. Le he estado dando vueltas al asunto pero no veo el por qué me pasa el error. Les agradecería si pudieran ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

**USER** es una palabra reservada que no te permite usarla para la base de datos en postgres. [documenation de postgres con palabras reservadas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Agrega otro nombre.

```
@Table(name="users")
@Entity
public class User { .. }
```